How do I prevent this cloth simulation from passing through each other?
I already checked self collision but it makes the cloth simulation crumpled. How do I make make them bounce, or at least not passing through each other? Blend File

Distance between vertices is less or around the distance between self-collusion. In this case, the nearest vertices start to collide with each other.

Set self collusion distance 5-10 times smaller than distance between points.
